# images are stacking on top of one another instead of inline

Tags: html, css

[image: What I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE]I've been at this for days. In my website, the images are stacking up on top of each other, so it appears to be a single image instead of 4. Also, it is displaying itself on top of other elements on the page, like the text. In Dreamweaver it shows up how I want, but in the browser, it shows as described above.

What I want: the four images to display side by side above the page header About Us.
Here is the code:

```
<center>
<span class="images">
<img src="images/aboutUs/longJumpBoy.jpg" alt="longJumpBoy" longdesc="images/aboutUs/longJumpBoy.jpg">
<img src="images/aboutUs/groupPic.jpg" alt="groupPic" width="214" longdesc="images/aboutUs/groupPic.jpg">
<img src="images/aboutUs/kidOnTrack.jpg" alt="kidOnTrack" longdesc="images/aboutUs/kidOnTrack.jpg">
<img src="images/aboutUs/throwingKids.jpg" alt="throwingKids" longdesc="images/aboutUs/throwingKids.jpg">

 </span> 

</center>

    <h1>About Us</h1>        
<br /><br />
    <h2>Who are we?</h2> 
<p>
    The team is a USA Track and Field (USATF) certified running club. We compete locally and nationally. Our athletes are able to train in all disciplines in track and field, but the team is specialized in distance running. Our runners are registered to run in both USATF and Amateur Athletic Union (AAU) league events.
    <br />
    Practices are held primarily on El Paso's East side.
</p>
 <header>
    <h2>Mission Statement</h2>
</header>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.images img {
    display:inline-block;
    border-color: rgb(191,224,104);
    border-width: 3px;
    margin: auto
}
```

EDIT: I edited the code and here is the link to my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JaLb7/ . Now, the image in browser displays above the text, but only one of them. Also, when I scroll, the image does not scroll with the page, but rather the text scrolls behind the image.

Image of my issue: [image: Preview in Browser - issues displaying]

Comment: Avoid using `<center>`, especially when using HTML5 tags too also I notice one of your image has a `width` attribute and not the others. And `longdesc` should contain text really as use by screen reader. Also is there more CSS than the one for the `img` tags? does `span.images` has any CSS?

Comment: Use `float:left` property. Or please create fiddle...

Comment: instead of `display:inline-block` try using `display:block`.

Comment: ...also don't use `<br/>` tags for separation, use margins & padding.

Comment: @user3486667: Want post an image use this link, imgur.com

Comment: I thought that block meant to stack them underneath each other?

Comment: Also, I have gotten rid of the <center> tag after using the W3C validation feature. When I created the fiddle, it looked like I wanted it to, but when I use display in browser, it looks botched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this is an amateur mistake. After digging through my stylesheet, I saw I had a img tag definition for styles (not part of a class) - which had a fixed positioning. We are looking much better now.

Thanks for all your help and suggestions, I did clean up my code per your recommendations - which helped in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could use display, text-align and white-space:

Your HTML

```
<span class="images">
<img src="images/aboutUs/longJumpBoy.jpg" alt="longJumpBoy" longdesc="images/aboutUs/longJumpBoy.jpg">
<img src="images/aboutUs/groupPic.jpg" alt="groupPic" width="214" longdesc="images/aboutUs/groupPic.jpg">
<img src="images/aboutUs/kidOnTrack.jpg" alt="kidOnTrack" longdesc="images/aboutUs/kidOnTrack.jpg">
<img src="images/aboutUs/throwingKids.jpg" alt="throwingKids" longdesc="images/aboutUs/throwingKids.jpg">
 </span>
```

Basis CSS to apply

```
.images {
display:block;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**Notice**,  should be a block element like `<p>` or `<div>` or even `<figure>` if that's accurate.

`<center>` should not be used and is totally useless as soon as you know how to apply `margin:auto;` and , or , `text-align:center;`.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JaLb7/

Also, I will attempt to attach a picture now. I wrapped it in <section> tags and now the image does display above the rest of the text on the page, but only one, not all. Also, when you scroll, it stays in place and the entire screen scrolls behind the image(s).